# Thread fails sometime using Task.Factory called by Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

first of all, sorry for the very long code part , I simplified it and tried to create a test class, but it's still very long, sorry again...

I'm struggling with some multithreading code and I would appreciate your help 
I use the Parallel Class with a ForEach Loop which calls some Methods, but sometimes (not always !) fails.

here my code:

```
public class SomeInstallClass
{

    public void main()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("someExe1.exe");
        list.Add("someExe2.exe");
        list.Add("someExe3.exe");
        list.Add("someExe4.exe");

        parallelInstallation(list);
    }


    private System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();

    private void parallelInstallation(List<string> exeStrings)
    {
        var po = new ParallelOptions();
        po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;

        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(exeStrings, po, t => { executeProcessSO(t); });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("catch of the Parallel Executions: " + e.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");
    }





    private ProcessStartInfo getProcessStartInfoSO(string someExe)
    {
        //Process myProcess = new Process();
        //string fullExe = string.Concat("\"", installUtilFile, "\"");
        ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(someExe, "");
        myProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "someWorkingDirectory";
        myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;//no standard input / output / error if true 
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        return myProcessStartInfo;
    }

    public void executeProcessSO(string someExe)
    {
        string standardOutput = string.Empty;
        string standardError = string.Empty;
        string exit = string.Empty;

        ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = getProcessStartInfoSO(someExe);
        exit = executeProcessSO(myProcessStartInfo, out standardOutput, out standardError);
        Console.WriteLine("Process completed");
    }

    private string executeProcessSO(ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo, out string standardOutput, out string standardError)
    {
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, args) =>
        {
            string err = string.Empty;
            foreach (var ex in args.Exception.InnerExceptions)
            {
                //Log(ex);
                err = err + "\n" + ex.Message;
                err = err + "\nStacktrace:" + ex.StackTrace; ;

                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    err = err + "\n" + ex.InnerException.Message;
                    err = err + "\nStacktrace" + ex.InnerException.StackTrace;
                }
            }
            EventLog.WriteEntry("InstallationService", "Error in executeProcess occured: \n" + err, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            args.SetObserved();
        };
        int exitCode;
        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
            using (Task taskWaiter = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => process.Start()))
            {
                try
                {
                    //1. run main task in specified time
                    taskWaiter.Wait(10000);

                    //2. if is not completed by now, kill it
                    if (!(taskWaiter.IsCompleted))
                    {
                        if (!process.HasExited)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                process.Kill();
                                process.WaitForExit(10000); //just to be sure...
                                standardError = "Timeout occured";
                                standardOutput = string.Empty;
                                EventLog.WriteEntry("InstallationService", standardError);


                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                standardError = "Timeout occured and exception occured during the kill operation. Ex: " + e.Message;
                                standardOutput = string.Empty;
                                throw e;
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception oe)
                {
                    standardError = "Exception in the taskWaiter occured. Ex: " + oe.Message;
                    throw oe;
                }

                //this point should be reached only if the process didn't timed out --> in this case read the output and error

                //using (Task<bool> processWaiter = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => process.WaitForExit(timeOutInMilliseconds)))
                using (Task<string> outputReader = Task.Factory.StartNew((Func<object, string>)ReadStream, process.StandardOutput))
                using (Task<string> errorReader = Task.Factory.StartNew((Func<object, string>)ReadStream, process.StandardError))
                {


                    //3. wait for the output reader and error reader to complete (if not already done)
                    Task.WaitAll(taskWaiter, outputReader, errorReader);

                    standardError = errorReader.Result;
                    standardOutput = outputReader.Result;


                    try
                    {
                        process.WaitForExit(10000); //just to be sure...
                        exitCode = process.ExitCode;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e2)
                    {
                        EventLog.WriteEntry("InstallationService", "Error in process.WaitForExit occured: \n" + e2.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                        throw e2;
                    }


                }
            }
        }

        if (exitCode.Equals(0))
            return "Success";
        else
            return "Failed";
    }

    private string ReadStream(object streamReader)
    {
        string result = ((StreamReader)streamReader).ReadToEnd();
        return result;
    }





}
```

The problem here is , that sometimes I get this error (which I can see in the EventLog):

Error in executeProcess occured:

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Process'.
Stacktrace:   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at ProcessHelper.Execution.c__DisplayClass7.b__4()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InvokeFuture(Object futureAsObj)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

I have no idea what is wrong here, hope you could give me some advice. thanks a lot.

Comment: The code as posted is too long to be analyzed in a reasonable amount of time. Post a minimal repro. This is required on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I looked over your code in depth, and I have the following Qs: 1. Why are you starting the process in a different thread, using task factory? 2. Why are you not using `process.WaitForExit(timeout)`? 3. What are you trying to accomplish with this ultimately?

Comment: I suggest that you log `e2.ToString()` instead of `e2.Message` to get important information about the exception. Also see [How do I log exception information to allow troubleshooting?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11898294/98607)

Comment: Where is `ProcessHelper.Execution` as shown in the exception? Or alternatively, why aren't you showing a stack trace from the code you actually posted? There certainly seems to be way more code here than should be minimally required. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your valuable Input. I try to run an installutil installation in paralell. I am interested if on the exitcode and on the standard and error output. Actually, I used the TaskWaiter to avoid locking when reading the standard error and output. I removed now the taskwaiter and run the process directly, I put the changes in my solution below (executeProcessSO Method). Do you mean it works in any situation (giving back the standar and error output?)

Comment: Martin, thanks for the input about the exception handling, very usefull!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question of theMayer, I was wondering if I really need the task factory and I realized that I do not, so I replaced the Method executeProcessSO and now it works.

```
    private string executeProcessSO(ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo, out string standardOutput, out string standardError)
    {
        string rslt = "Failed";
        int exitCode = -1;

        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
            process.Start();

            using (Task<string> outputReader = Task.Factory.StartNew((Func<object, string>)ReadStream, process.StandardOutput))
            using (Task<string> errorReader = Task.Factory.StartNew((Func<object, string>)ReadStream, process.StandardError))
            {
                process.WaitForExit(10000);

                standardError = errorReader.Result;
                standardOutput = outputReader.Result;


                try
                {
                    if (process.HasExited)
                    {
                        exitCode = process.ExitCode;
                        if (exitCode.Equals(0))
                            rslt = "Success";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        process.Kill();
                        rslt = "Timeout";
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e2)
                {
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("InstallationService", "Error in process.WaitForExit occured: \n" + e2.Message.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    throw e2;
                }
            }
        }

        return rslt;
    }
```